# Select SDK path not specified

Tags: android-studio, sdk

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnmgA.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5y7X.png)

Need to specify the path for the android sdk files

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need an SDK in order to simulate whichever android API you're running against, download an SDK, put it in a folder somewhere (like C:\SDK) then link it.